# How to get Shipment method wise suppliers with most order quantity?

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group, row-number

I am having difficulties to understand  when to use subqueries and how to implement them in a way that makes sense.

I have the following tables:

Table `supplier`:

| supplier_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Supplier#0000001 |
| 2 | Supplier#0000002 |
| 4 | Supplier#0000003 |
| 3 | Supplier#0000004 |
| ... | ... |

Table `orderitem`:

| order_id | shippingmethod | supplier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUCK | 134 |
| 2 | MAIL | 345 |
| 3 | REG AIR | 223 |
| 4 | REG AIR | 11345 |
| 5 | RAIL | 344 |
| ... | ... | 535 |

I want to find the supplier with the highest amount of shipped `order_items` for each shipping method. So my end result should look this:

| shippingmethod | suppliername | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUCK | Supplier#0000002 | 120 |
| MAIL | Supplier#0003453 | 590 |
| REG AIR | Supplier#0003456 | 433 |
| AIR | Supplier#0000632 | 244 |
| SHIP | Supplier#0000654 | 566 |

I came up with this:

```
SELECT 
    SHIPPINGMETHOD, SUPPLIERNAME, COUNT(ORDER_ID) AS AMOUNT
FROM 
    ORDERITEM
JOIN 
    SUPPLIER L ON L.SUPPLIER_ID = ORDERITEM.SUPPLIER
GROUP BY 
    SHIPPINGMETHOD, SUPPLIERNAME;
```

But this only returns the amount of shipped items of each supplier of each shipping method.

So then I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    SHIPPINGMETHOD, L.SUPPLIERNAME, COUNT(OI.ORDER_ID) AS AMOUNT
FROM 
    ORDERITEM AS OI
JOIN 
    SUPPLIER L ON L.SUPPLIER_ID = OI.SUPPLIER
GROUP BY 
    OI.SHIPPINGMETHOD, L.SUPPLIERNAME
HAVING 
    COUNT(OI.ORDER_ID) = (SELECT MAX(AMOUNT)
                          FROM 
                              (SELECT 
                                   OI2.SHIPPINGMETHOD, L2.SUPPLIERNAME, 
                                   COUNT(OI2.ORDER_ID) AS AMOUNT
                               FROM 
                                   ORDERITEM AS OI2
                               JOIN 
                                   SUPPLIER L2 ON L2.SUPPLIER_ID = OI2.SUPPLIER
                               GROUP BY 
                                   OI.SHIPPINGMETHOD, L.SUPPLIERNAME) AS SUB
);
```

I only get **one** row back. The row shows the correct supplier and the correct amount of shipped items for one of the methods, but I expected **5** rows. I feel like I am very close, but honestly have no clue at all what my mistake actually is.

Comment: Do you want to find the shipping method wise suppliers with highest order quantity?

Comment: Please mention the dbms name.

Comment: Yes there is 5 shipping methods and I want to find for each the supplier who has the biggest amount of orderitems (basically shipped items) sorry if its confusing.

Comment: I use db2 as DBMS

Comment: please check the answer then. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find shipping method wise suppliers with highest order quantity then you can try this:

** here `row_number()over()` window function is used to rank the supplier in descending order of order quantity.

Query:

```
with cte as 
(
SELECT shippingmethod, L.name suppliername , COUNT(order_id) AS AMOUNT,
row_number()over(partition by shippingmethod, L.name order by COUNT(order_id) desc) as rn 
FROM orderitem
JOIN supplier L on L.supplier_id = orderitem.SUPPLIER
GROUP BY shippingmethod, L.name
)
select shippingmethod, suppliername , AMOUNT from cte
where rn=1
```

Output:

| shippingmethod | suppliername | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MAIL | Supplier#0000002 | 1 |
| RAIL | Supplier#0000004 | 1 |
| REG AIR | Supplier#0000004 | 1 |
| TRUCK | Supplier#0000001 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/peIIuwJu)

*** If there are more than one customer with highest order quantity all of those would be in the list.